# Duplicate questions about Slack v4.27.154

Tags: discussion, duplicates

It appears that Slack v 4.27.154, which was released 3 days ago, isn't working for some users, and the official workaround from Slack support is to downgrade to an older version. We right now have 4 questions about this:

1. [Slack refusing to start](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1416364/slack-refusing-to-start)
2. [Slack not starting after update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1416589/slack-not-starting-after-update)
3. [How to get past `apparmor="DENIED" operation="open"`?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1416329/how-to-get-past-apparmor-denied-operation-open)
4. [Updating Slack breaks it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1416275/updating-slack-breaks-it)

[this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1416364/slack-refusing-to-start/1416376#1416376) to the first question listed seems to be the most detailed, although it only describes how to do so for apt packages, not deb or flatpak ones.

Can we get these closed as duplicates?

Comment: Thanks for finding this! Have you flagged them as duplicates? That's usually the fastest way.

Comment: I just flagged the one I didn't get yet; it seemed slightly different the first time I read it but now on closer look it's most likely the same issue, so I flagged it too. The others were flagged already

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some great detective work! I have closed 2-4 as duplicates of your number 1 question as there is a basic premise of: Slack currently is broken, revert to an older version. Doubtless there will be more new questions along the same line...

There are some choices when you have found such a run of dupes, and I make the following list *in no particular order*:

- Make a post on Meta (as you have done)
- Leave a polite note under the question querying a Duplicate (as you have done)
- [Flag for closing as a Duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/close-questions) and let the community decide (3,000 Rep)
- Discuss the issue on chat, with [Raiders of the lost downboat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3877/raiders-of-the-lost-downboat) being a great choice

And thanks @Esther for making the effort!